# How to use pologon postgis on query in spring-boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, postgis

I got this exception when excute the below query I use postgis how to use pologon on a right way

### could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

```
    @Query(name = "getCellIdsForRectangle", value = "SELECT * FROM lk_location as lk "
        + "LEFT JOIN lk_slocation as s "
        + "ON ST_DWithin(POLYGON((-4.43 54.31,-4.39 54.31,-4.39 54.29,-4.43 54.29,-4.43 54.31))\\:\\:GEOMETRY, ST_MakePoint(s.longitude,s.latitude)\\:\\:geometry, s.range) "
        + "WHERE ST_DWithin(POLYGON((-4.43 54.31,-4.39 54.31,-4.39 54.29,-4.43 54.29,-4.43 54.31))\\:\\:GEOMETRY, ST_MakePoint(lk.longitude,lk.latitude)\\:\\:geometry, lk.range) AND s.location_id IS NULL;", nativeQuery = true)
List<Location> getCellIdsForRectangle();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are constructing a polygon from text, so the polygon must be quoted

```
  + "ON ST_DWithin('POLYGON((-4.43 54.31,-4.39 54.31,-4.39 54.29,-4.43 54.29,-4.43 54.31))'\\:\\:GEOMETRY, ST_MakePoint(s.longitude,s.latitude)\\:\\:geometry, s.range) "
```

Comment: I have got this error after you edit

No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111

Comment: 'POLYGON((:longitude1 :latitude1,:longitude2 :latitude2,:longitude3 :latitude3,:longitude4 :latitude4,:longitude1 :latitude1)) @JGH